# compare File 2(Include substrings/strings) against File 1(include strings) and store only the first match line from File 1

Tags: bash, file, compare

I have 2 files

**File 1**

```
A0001  C001
B0003  C896
A0024  C234
B1542  C231
A0001  C001
A0024  C234
```

up to 15000 such lines.

**File 2**

```
B1542
A0024  C234
A0001
A0024
```

and 5000 such lines.

I want to compare File 2(Include substrings/strings) against File 1(include strings) and store the only the first match line from File 1 so the final result should be like this:

```
B1542  C231
A0024  C234
A0001  C001
A0024  C234
```

I tried to use awk or grep but I am not even close to the final solution

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' file2 file1
```

This awk prints me only the full matches - it ignores if substring includes

```
grep -Ff File2 File1
```

This grep prints me all matches and not only the first match

Thanks for helping

P.S. File 1 can be with duplicate strings

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in form of code. Could you please be more clear in your sample of input and expected output in your question. Kindly do edit your samples and let us know then.

Comment: Let say for this sample only the 4 substrings from file 2 appears in file 1, so it's print the only 4 matches from file 1 by the order of they appear in file 2

Comment: I would like to request you to please edit your question with more clear samples for better understanding thank you.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help me.
If you have questions if something is unclear, ask, and I will answer, I think the example I gave here satisfies the needs.
I would be happy to answer if anything is unclear

Comment: Considering you want to print only first matches found you please try `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print;delete a[$1]}' file2 file1` and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: It's doesn't work fine

Comment: Why `A0024  C234` appears twice in your expected result ?

Comment: It should appear twice because A0024  C234 and A0024  appear in file 2

Comment: For the given samples, what would be the output if the second line of the file2 were `A0024  C000`? Ditto for `A0024 C001` ?

Comment: Every line from file 2 should be part or full at least 1 line from file 1
So if line 2 of file 2 is A0024  C000 instead of A0024  C234, so the output should be without that line.
The result should be:

B1542  C231
A0001  C001
A0024  C234

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear and there's some edge cases not covered by it so I'm not sure but this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( !($1 in key2val) ) {
        key2val[$1] = $0
    }
    next
}
$1 in key2val {
    $0 = key2val[$1]
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
B1542  C231
A0024  C234
A0001  C001
A0024  C234
```